# window.resize not on scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a jQuery code that slide/toggles the navigation. After that I reset the style-attribute in the HTML, with window.resize, so that the Navigation will appear, if the browser-window is resized. The code for that is here:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $("nav").removeAttr('style');
    $(".level_2").removeAttr('style');
    $(".menu-expander").removeClass('close');
});
```

Now I have the problem, that the navigation is displayed off, when I scroll down on the smartphone or change from the portrait-view to landscape, e.g. when I have a long navigation.

Is there a possibilty to check, if there was just changed the view or was scrolled on the page, so that the window.resize could just appear when the browserwindow is resized?

PS: Here is the code on Codepen: http://codepen.io/Sukrams/pen/NxQoYr

Comment: It's hard to understand exactly what you're trying to do, but it sounds like CSS Media Queries would be better suited to your goals.

Comment: I open/close my naivgation mobile with slideToggle. It sets a display:block or display:none to the navigation. When I resize the browserwindow and the navigation was toggled before, so the navigation has the attribute display:none. So I reset the style-attribute with the resize-function.

But right now I have the problem that it appears too, when I scroll on my mobile phone or change from portrait to landscape view. And I'm looking for a possibility to reset the style-attribute just when the browserwindow is resized.

Comment: could you post it via jsfiddle or plunker?

Comment: Yes, here it is: http://codepen.io/Sukrams/pen/NxQoYr

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: I set a variable for the width and put it into an if:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  var width = $(window).width();
  if(width > 700) {
    $("nav").removeAttr('style');
    $(".level_2").removeAttr('style');
    $(".menu-expander").removeClass('close');
  }
});
```